# Vba defaulting Varianel date to 12:00am causing subscript out of range error

Tags: arrays, vba, loops

VBA is defaulting my variable date from user input to 12:00am, which results in a subscript out of range error later on. I have declared all the variables correctly, it was working previously but now it is not. Any ideas on what to check for?  Ive tried adjusting things using DateAdd and as well as trying to get vba to add # to both ends of the variable setting line. The strange thing is, that before now vba was accepting the user input of the date (LastEndDateV) and passing it correctly. Is there something whacky going on with the loop?

I guess its worth mentioning that the user input is from a text box from a user form, however this has not been an issue until now.

sample code

```
 Dim BlockEnd As Date: Dim BlcokStart As Date
 Dim LastStartV As Date
 Dim LastEndDateV As Date
 Dim UACFArray(3, 1) As Date

 LastEndDateV = LastEndDateV.Value
 BlcokStart = LastEndDateV + 7
 BlockEnd = LastEndDateV + BlockLength
 TotalC = CSched
 TotalW = WSched
 CareerComb = CareerTypeCombo.Value
 Debug.Print "Values"; BlcokStart, BlockEnd, TotalC, TotalW

 UACFArray(0, 0) = #1/6/2015#: UACFArray(0, 1) = #2/3/2015#
 UACFArray(1, 0) = #1/20/2015#: UACFArray(1, 1) = #2/17/2015#
 UACFArray(2, 0) = #2/10/2015#: UACFArray(2, 1) = #3/10/2015#
 UACFArray(3, 0) = #2/24/2015#: UACFArray(3, 1) = #3/24/2015#

For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    If CFChk = True Then
        Select Case CareerComb
        Case Is = "Test1", "Test2"
            For l = LBound(UACFArray, 1) To UBound(UACFArray, 1)
                If BlcokStart = UACFArray(l, 0) Then
                    For m = LBound(UACFArray, 2) To UBound(UACFArray, 2)
                        BlockEnd = UACFArray(l, m)
                        a(i) = BlcokStart & " & " & BlockEnd
                        TotalC = TotalC + 3
                        TotalW = TotalW + CWs
                        BlcokStart = UACFArray(l + 1, 0) ******subscript occurs here
                    Next m
```

Here is what I tested it with initially before moving it into the main part of my original code:

```
Sub loopchecker()

Dim UACFArray(8, 1) As Date
Dim checkpoint As Date
Dim Block As String

checkpoint = #2/11/2015#

UACFArray(0, 0) = #1/6/2015#: UACFArray(0, 1) = #2/3/2015#
UACFArray(1, 0) = #1/20/2015#: UACFArray(1, 1) = #2/17/2015#
UACFArray(2, 0) = #2/10/2015#: UACFArray(2, 1) = #3/10/2015#
UACFArray(3, 0) = #2/24/2015#: UACFArray(3, 1) = #3/24/2015#
UACFArray(4, 0) = #3/17/2015#: UACFArray(4, 1) = #4/14/2015#
UACFArray(5, 0) = #3/31/2015#: UACFArray(5, 1) = #4/28/2015#
UACFArray(6, 0) = #4/21/2015#: UACFArray(6, 1) = #5/19/2015#
UACFArray(7, 0) = #5/5/2015#: UACFArray(7, 1) = #6/2/2015#
UACFArray(8, 0) = #5/26/2015#: UACFArray(8, 1) = #6/23/2015#

For x = LBound(UACFArray, 1) To UBound(UACFArray, 1)
    If checkpoint = UACFArray(x, 0) Then
        Block = UACFArray(x, 0)
        For y = LBound(UACFArray, 2) To UBound(UACFArray, 2)
            Block = UACFArray(x, 0) & " " & "-" & " " & UACFArray(x, y)
        Next y
    ElseIf checkpoint <> UACFArray(x, 0) Then
        For y = LBound(UACFArray, 2) To UBound(UACFArray, 2)
            If checkpoint > UACFArray(x, 0) And checkpoint < UACFArray(x, y) Then
                Block = UACFArray(x + 1, 0)
                Block = Block & " " & "-" & " " & UACFArray(x + 1, y)
            End If
        Next y
    End If
Next x

Debug.Print "Block = "; Block

End Sub
```

With this version everything worked correctly however I did not try and reset value of blockstart(as this needs to be readjusted each step)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping the array like this:

```
For l = LBound(UACFArray, 1) To UBound(UACFArray, 1)
```

Which will mean that during that loop, `l` is always a valid index for the array.

The problem is this line:

```
BlcokStart = UACFArray(l + 1, 0)
```

`l+1` will raise the error, because `l+1` will be out of bounds where `l = UBound(UACFArray, 1)`.

It looks like you're trying to assing `BlcokStart` as the *next* value in the array, but when `l = Ubound(UACFArray, 1)`, there is not a *next* value, you've reached the *end* of the array.

There are several ways to resolve this, but the correct solution depends on what you expect the resulting value *should* be, when you reach the end of the array.

Most simply, you could do:

```
For l = LBound(UACFArray, 1) To (UBound(UACFArray, 1) - 1)
```

But that will not work if you still need to process the `For m...` loop. In that case, probably you just need an `Exit` statment, like:

```
        For l = LBound(UACFArray, 1) To UBound(UACFArray, 1)
            If BlcokStart = UACFArray(l, 0) Then
                For m = LBound(UACFArray, 2) To UBound(UACFArray, 2)
                    BlockEnd = UACFArray(l, m)
                    a(i) = BlcokStart & " & " & BlockEnd
                    TotalC = TotalC + 3
                    TotalW = TotalW + CWs
                    If l = UBound(UACFArray,1) Then Exit For '### Exit early, since the next line will be out of bounds error
                    BlcokStart = UACFArray(l + 1, 0) 
                Next m
```

**IF** you still need to reset `BlcokStart` to some other value, then use `If/Else`:

```
                If l = UBound(UACFArray,1) Then 
                    BlcokStart = # Some Date Value #   
                    Exit For '### Exit early
                Else
                    BlcokStart = UACFArray(l + 1, 0) 
                End If
```

Comment: The problem ive found through stepping through is that the value of BlcokStart = 12:00am, which is the real issue. I understand what youre saying and it makes sense but the issue is with vba taking my user input value and then setting it to 12:00am.

Comment: @DougCoats  You need to show how you're capturing the user input, and example of what user input is being improperly converted to 12:00am please.

Comment: Further, while the value of `BlcokStart` may be incorrect, *that* is definitely *not* causing the Subscript out of Range error on the assignment statement you've highlighted. The error is definitely due to referencing an index out of bounds. If you can show more code, I can probably fix the `BlcokStart` variable error, too, though.

Comment: Yes. See revised answer.

Comment: Hey, in the above example LastEndDateV is defined as Date. I also have already tried to use DateAdd as well.

Comment: @DougCoats **NO** in the example you provided `LastEndDateV` is absolutely **not** defined as a date, it's not defined at all.

Comment: Corrected. They are most certainly defined in my Sub though. Error in transferring from module to site. Sorry

Comment: Also I added this to the code to find values on execution. The debug.Print shows that BlcokStart does carry the correct value from the user input.

Comment: OK. Then my original answer stands. Your problem is in the loop, not the value of `BlcokStart` variable, since you're assinging **to** that variable when the error raises, so the error is happening on the *right* side of the assignment statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106628/discussion-between-david-zemens-and-doug-coats).